# Why a subshell is needed to execute some commands?

Tags: command-line

I have to run this command `sudo sh -c "echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolv.conf"` to append a line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` into `/etc/resolv.conf` file. I know, it could be possible only through subshell.

**My questions:**

- Is that it could be possible without running the command in  subshell?
- On which cases, a command should be runned in subshell?

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to know why you should warp the redirection while using sudo or in which cases you have to run subshells?

Comment: Can you clarify? In your example`sudo sh -c ...` doesn't create a subshell, but a new shell process (and you don't need this new shell as long as you can use `sed` or `tee` or something else instead of `>>`). And `>>` is not a real command to use `sudo` on it, but is an [redirection operator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). So, your question doesn't have sense, or logic...

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

fails because it gives elevated permissions to the `echo` command (which doesn't need it), but not to the `>>` redirection (which does, since the destination file is owned by root). Wrapping the whole command sequence in `sudo sh` overcomes that.

You could also do

```
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Using the pipeline, you are using in fact not one subshell, but two. See `man bash` in this sense (line 279): *"Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e.,  in a subshell)."*